# Building my Nuxt3 app on a low spec system

Tags: server, nuxt.js, debian, nuxtjs3

I am running a debian 11 server with 512mb of RAM. I want to host my Nuxt3 app there (just for personal use, not for production use). When I am running `npm run build` I get the following error:

```
<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 0xb02930 node::Abort() [node]
 2: 0xa18149 node::FatalError(char const*, char const*) [node]
 3: 0xcdd16e v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node]
 4: 0xcdd4e7 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node]
 5: 0xe94b55  [node]
 6: 0xea481d v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [node]
 7: 0xea751e v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFailSlowPath(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [node]
 8: 0xe68a5a v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject(int, bool, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin) [node]
 9: 0x11e17c6 v8::internal::Runtime_AllocateInYoungGeneration(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [node]
10: 0x15d5439  [node]
Aborted
```

I already tried something like `npm run build -- --max-old-space-size=128` but the problem ist still the same. I already tried building on my windows machine and just running the output on the server but that did not work aswell because the code was compiled on another system.
Does anybody have an idea of how I can build an run the server now?

Comment: Not sure if there is a magic sauce here. Can't you allow more memory? 512MB seems quite low nowadays. Also, are you sure that 128 is in MB? Could be B or kB idk.

Comment: Yeah I guess my half GB of RAM was just a bit to optimistic. I am probably just going to increase